# Does monotouch supports AirPlay?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is it possible to add AirPlay to stream video with the MPMoviePlayerController? I couldn't find it in the documentation, and the MonoTouch 3.2.5 release notes doesn't mention anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes MonoTouch supports AirPlay, you'll need to install MonoTouch 4 which has support for iOS 4.3 APIs.

Comment: OK but MonoTouch 4 is alpha so I guess the correct answer is as of 2011.4.1 "not yet", which is too bad, but understandable.

Comment: MonoTouch 4 is in Beta, with a release imminent.

Comment: This is great news! I was just quoting from monotouch.net where they mentioned the release of 4.0 alpha on Monday (I guess that is a long gone Monday). The Monotouch team is really amazing.

Comment: at compile time monotouch returns an error the the property MonoTouch.MediaPlayer.MPMoviePlayerController.AllowsAirPlay is Read Only!

Comment: This was a bug, and is fixed in 4.0.1 which will be out soon.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Airplay in Objective-C, all you have to do is set the allowsAirPlay property on the MPMoviePlayerController.

```
myMPMoviePlayerController.allowsAirPlay = YES;
```

Although this is objective c syntax, I'd have thought you could do the same with mono as well since it's just setting a library property?